# Line 247 of bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_top-bar.scss: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'

Tags: zurb-foundation

By Updating the foundation I got this error 
Line 247 of bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_top-bar.scss: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'.

Answer (score 1):

The $topbar-height variable in the _tobbar.scss is in rem-calc, but i gave the $topbar-height value in pixel in my _setting.scss, so the rem and px incompatible error came so please chnage the px value in the setting.scss into the rem-calc for example
if u gave like this in pixel 
$topbar-height: 50px;
please change that into 
$topbar-height: rem-calc(50);

Thanks :) happy coding